# How do I make a circular border with Flutter's PhysicalModel?

Tags: geometry, border, flutter

I'm trying to make a circular border within a PhysicalModel. It works if I don't wrap my widget in a PhysicalModel, but once I do, I get a square-ish border.

```
new PhysicalModel(
  color: Colors.green,
  child: new Container(
    width: 50.0,
    height: 50.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
      border: new Border.all(
        width: 5.0,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to also define the borderRadius in the PhysicalModel widget.

```
new PhysicalModel(
  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
  ... // stuff from above
),
```

in addition to defining the borderRadius in the BoxDecoration.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the shape - circle

```
PhysicalModel(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,  //Here
),
```

Answer (score 0):

decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            ),
          ),